# The return statement not working as expected

Tags: return

So I am trying to write a function which edits a dataframe in place- drops a column and adds another column to it. Within the function I am getting the expected output, but when I am trying to print the dataframe outside the function, it is still printing the original values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def login_table(id_name_verified, id_password):
    """
    :param id_name_verified: (DataFrame) DataFrame with columns: Id, Login, Verified.   
    :param id_password: (numpy.array) Two-dimensional NumPy array where each element
                        is an array that contains: Id and Password
    :returns: (None) The function should modify id_name_verified DataFrame in-place. 
              It should not return anything.
    """   
    password= pd.DataFrame(data=id_password[:,1],columns=["Password"])
    id_name_verified = id_name_verified.join(password["Password"])
    id_name_verified.drop("Verified",axis=1,inplace=True)
    return id_name_verified

id_name_verified = pd.DataFrame([[1, "JohnDoe", True], [2, "AnnFranklin", False]], columns=["Id", "Login", "Verified"])
global id_name_verified
id_password = np.array([[1, 987340123], [2, 187031122]], np.int32)
login_table(id_name_verified, id_password)
print(id_name_verified)
```

The last print statement is still printing:

```
   Id        Login  Verified
0   1      JohnDoe      True
1   2  AnnFranklin     False
```

What am I missing? I am new to python. Please help!

Comment: Can anybody please help me here?

Answer (score 1):

So instead of the join I had to use the loc function to add the password to the id_name_verified dataframe:

```
def login_table(id_name_verified, id_password):

    password = pd.DataFrame(id_password, columns=["Id", "Password"])
    id_name_verified.loc[:, 'Password'] = password['Password']
    id_name_verified.drop("Verified",axis=1,inplace=True)
    return None
```

This did the trick.